# WOFF2 conversion from standard WOFF

Tags: typography, woff, woff2

I've seen that some Google Webfonts now use WOFF 2.0. Can I somehow convert my existing WOFF-fonts to this new (and supposedly better format)? And how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could't find any WOFF to WOFF2 converters, but you can easy convert your current WOFF font to TTF with any service like [this](http://everythingfonts.com/woff-to-ttf). And then using this [WOFF2 cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/sergejmueller/cf6b4f2133bcb3e2f64a), convert TTF to WOFF2.

I tested those steps with my fonts, converted font *WOFF -> TTF -> WOFF2* works fine.

Answer (score 30):

Certainly! You can convert the existing woff files to the new format. You will get more than 30% improvement on the compression ratio.

Even though browser support is limited at this moment

http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2

It will eventually change. You should use the @font-face fall back and start putting these kind of directives in your css now.

```
 @font-face {
   font-family: MyFont;
   src:
       url('font.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('font.woff') format('woff');
  }
```

You can use the following tools to convert from ttf/woff to woff2.0

http://everythingfonts.com/woff-to-woff2

https://github.com/google/woff2

Answer (score 5):

I managed to convert with 
https://everythingfonts.com/woff-to-woff2
did it for my fontawseome icons

Answer (score 2):

[Font Squirrel generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) now includes WOFF2 in it's generated fonts.  So you can create it that way from your TTF file.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, you can convert WOFF to OTF/TTF and then to WOFF2:

```
woff2sfnt myfont.woff > myfont.ttf
woff2_compress myfont.ttf
```

Package dependencies:

```
sudo apt install woff-tools woff2
```